# Amazon S3 Bucket Setup For Recording Sinch Calls

Tags: amazon-s3, recording, sinch

I have contacted Sinch support and they have informed me that my access key, secret key, and bucket name are ready to go from their point of view.

My next step (I believe) is to configure the Amazon S3 bucket itself.
I'm not sure if this is through
 1. the bucket Public Access (I have "Block all Public Access" turned off for this bucket) 
 2. the CORS configuration
 3. the ACL, or 
 4. the Bucket Control Policy

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated from the Amazon S3 bucket side of things.

I have set my bucket up to have the following CORS configuration and would like some insight into whether this is correct to work with Sinch. I don't know if AllowedOrigin for sinch is correct.

I have also pasted my callback ICE response in PHP if there are errors there for recording.

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.mywebsite.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>






Below is my ICE response. It does not connect calls
when I have it configured this way but I'm not sure
if it's due to an ICE response structure error or amazon bucket setup error.
I have been using this documentation link but find it somewhat confusing:
https://developers.sinch.com/docs/voice-rest-api-recording

$ice_response = 
array(
    "instructions"=>array(
        array("name"=>"Say","text"=>"Hello listeners","locale"=>"en-US"),
        array(
            "name:=>"StartRecording",
            "options"=>array(
                "destinationUrl"=>"s3://mybucketname/test-file.mp3",
                "credentials"=>"accesskey:secretkey:region_code",
                "format"=>"mp3",
                "notificationEvents"=>true
            )
        ),
        array("name"=>"Say","text"=>"Recording started","locale"=>"en-US")
    ),
    "action"=>array(
        "name" => "connectConf",
        "conferenceId" => $post["to"]["endpoint"],
        "record" => true 
    )
);
echo json_encode($ice_response);
```